# ConnectionState Enumeration - Determining Database Status

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database

I am trying to write a background process that checks to see if a database is broken and I am a little bit confused on what exactly would constitute as "broken".

Looking at the official documentation found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.connectionstate.aspx) on the Microsoft Developers Network for ConnectionState there is a member entitled "broken". At what point would this member result to true, or how exactly would it be used?

This is currently how I am checking if the DB is broken:

```
    public bool DatabaseConnection()
    {
        bool statusUp = true;

        using (var databaseConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigData.ConnectionStrings.DatabaseConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                databaseConnection.Open()       
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                const string message = "Could not establish a connection with Database.";
                Log.DatabaseStatusDown(message, ex);
                statusUp = false; 
            }
            finally { databaseConnection.Close(); }
        }

        return statusUp
    }
```

I know Using statement leverages the IDisposable class and the connection will be disposed of but I am extra paranoid. Is this efficient? If not, would a more efficient way to determine if my connection is broken would be to do something like this?

```
public bool DatabaseConnection()
{
    using (var databaseConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigData.ConnectionStrings.DatabaseConnectionString))
    {
        return databaseConnection.State == ConnectionState.Broken;
    }
}
```

I will be running this process every two minutes, and something tells me the first method I outlined will not be efficient. Would the second method work to determine if my DB is broken? What exactly does Microsoft define as broken for this particular enum?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use ConnectionState.Broken.  It is [reserved for future use](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.connectionstate(v=vs.110).aspx).

The first technique is actually pretty lightweight.  All it does is get a connection from the connection pool, which is held locally.  Disposing the connection will return the connection to the pool for use by other processes.

I would perhaps consider actually sending a command to the SQL Server, e.g. "SELECT 'ping'" or something lightweight.  If you don't get a resultset back it indicates that your SQL Server couldn't service the request for whatever reason.

Comment: OKay makes sense. So doing this every two minutes will not be too heavy for the server?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of sending a command to the server... This might be a little extra bit of security for me to take to help determine the connection state.

Comment: No, it wouldn't be too heavy for the server.  `SELECT 1` is about as lightweight as you can get.

Comment: This is the best answer so far.

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert, but I believe broken would indicate that an already connected database connection had an unrecoverable connection issue (Server closed it, etc).   It wouldn't be very reliable, and then possibly only detectable after a failed attempt to do something.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to check for `Broken` on a connection you just made. It's only useful for a long-living connection - and it basically tells you to reopen the connection.

It doesn't tell you anything about the state of the database, or the database server. The only thing it tells you is whether the concrete *connection* is working or not.

If you're always creating new connections, the only thing you care about is whether `connection.Open` throws an exception or not. And of course, the `ExecuteXXX` methods etc. - the connection can drop at any point.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment... Can you think of a more optimal  alternative for me to do this? You mentioned checking for exceptions, but I am not quite sure on how that can be done.

Comment: @jacktor The DB is not going to be broken; even if it did, the connection state will not tell you that. It only tells you about the state of that exact connection, and nothing else. It's *you* who needs to figure out what it means for your DB to be "broken" :) Every interaction you make over any connection has to be covered in error handling code, making sure that you can never be stuck in an inconsistent state, as well as making sure the user is notified approprietly (and possibly logged out or whatever your approach is).

Comment: thank you very much for the information. The database is on a remote server and I dont have access to it. I was just told to make a process to determine if the database was broken and figured if it refused a connection it would be a good indication that it is broken...